# Need to build application for iPAD and for windows using WPF

Tags: .net, ipad, dll, architecture

I need to build a desktop application for windows using WPF and same application for iPAD as well. What I want is to keep some of the logic in one place for both the applications. for example making a dll and include this dll in both the projects etc.

My question is what is the best approach I should follow?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) product from Xamarin.

It lets you write C# for use on iOS, so you can at least have some common code between the iPad and the Windows ports.

Comment: Thanks Oded. It looks good to me. Is there any other idea for which I don't need to buy another product?

Comment: @TausifKhan - Nothing that I know of.

Comment: @TausifKhan, without MonoTouch, it is impossible to reuse your C# code on iOS development, so it worth the price. You can play with the free (simulator only) edition to explore its powers.

Comment: Thanks Lex Li. I will definitely going to consider it. But I need to just explore it a bit. May be I can contact you guys. Thanks for your support. Cheers

Comment: Hi guys, Is it possible to use C++ for developing common functionality for both?